# SQL Server stored procedure a lot slower than straight query

Tags: sql-server, performance, stored-procedures

I have a table with over 100MM records in it. The table has a clustered index and a nonclustered index.

I can run a basic count using T-SQL on the table and it takes 1 second to run. When I put the same exact count query inside of a stored procedure it then takes 12 seconds to run.

I have looked at the execution plan for both the standard query and the stored procedure and they both are using the nonclustered index.

I am not sure why the stored procedure is so slow compared to the standard query.

I have read some stuff about reindexing in a situation like this but I am not sure why I need to do that. Also, it takes a few hours to reindex so I want to make sure that will work.

Any help on this would be great.

Thanks

UPDATE

Here is the stored procedure:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE quickCount 

@sYID INT,
@eYID INT

AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;


    SELECT COUNT(leadID)
    FROM dbo.leads
    WHERE yearID >= @sYID
    AND yearID <= @eYID

END
GO
```

and here is the standard query:

```
SELECT COUNT(leadID)
FROM leads
WHERE yearID >= 0
AND yearID <= 99
```

I did try to run it with no parameters and the SP runs way faster (1 second). So I am assuming that it has something to do with the parameters.

Comment: CAn you show us a bit of the SP, doe you pass in any parameters?

Comment: I think you'll need to show your query and SP.

Comment: It can happen you've tried query with constants and your procedure use parameters instead of this constants. I suggest you to create SQLFiddle example or post some details about schema and query/sp

Comment: Do you run both against a "cold" page buffer? Or which one of the two do you run first? I would try to do `DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS` and `DBCC FREEPROCCACHE` before running either of the those two - does the execution time difference still occur? Or are both the same speed now?

Comment: Shouldn't matter afaik, but could you try the plain query with `SET ANSI_NULLS ON`?

Answer (score 18):

Try changing your SP to using local copies of the variables passed in.

Something like

```
ALTER PROCEDURE quickCount  

@sYID INT, 
@eYID INT 

AS 
BEGIN 

SET NOCOUNT ON; 
    DECLARE @Local_sYID INT, 
            @Local_eYID INT 
    SELECT  @Local_sYID = @sYID INT, 
            @Local_eYID = @eYID INT

    SELECT COUNT(leadID) 
    FROM dbo.leads 
    WHERE yearID >= @Local_sYID 
    AND yearID <= @Local_eYID 

END
```

I have found before that due to Parameter Snffing, a SP can run a lot slower, but the performance returns once you use copies of the variables.

[What is Parameter Sniffing ?](http://blogs.technet.com/b/mdegre/archive/2012/03/19/what-is-parameter-sniffing.aspx)

[SQL Server : Parameter Sniffing](http://www.practicalsqldba.com/2012/06/sql-server-parameter-sniffing.html)

Comment: Thanks for the help but I had already tried that. It's not making it any faster.

Comment: wow! thanks for that! I couldn't find the problem in my SP until I found this post! thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5):

As already mentioned, this could be a **parameter sniffing** problem. Try including the line:

```
OPTION (RECOMPILE)
```

at the end of your SQL query.

There is an article here explaining what parameter sniffing is: http://blogs.technet.com/b/mdegre/archive/2012/03/19/what-is-parameter-sniffing.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You could always try to execute it as dynamic sql:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE quickCount  

@sYID INT, 
@eYID INT 

AS 
BEGIN 
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(max)

    SELECT @SQL = '
    SELECT COUNT(leadID) 
    FROM dbo.leads 
    WHERE yearID >= '+CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),@sYID)+'
    AND yearID <=   '+CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),@eYID)

    EXEC (@SQL)
END
```

Answer (score 0):

The first time you run the stored procedure, SQL Server will have to compile the stored procedure, which can take some time. @Astander mentioned parameter sniffing - which is a valid point, and can skew your results.

Some other factors to consider are (whilst they shouldn't really explain your symptoms):

- You could force a locking level, e.g. `WITH (NOLOCK)` after the table name, which could resolve the issue (but note that you could get inaccurate results by doing that).
- You may need to update the statistics on the table or defragment the indexes

Answer (score 0):

```
EXEC sp_recompile N'dbo.MyStoredProc';
```

Did the trick for me. The stored proc was taking 13 seconds for run and the query takes 0.00 seconds. After running the above command, they both take 0.00 seconds :)